# Grouping the Ordered data 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the best way to display group data?

Currently in my controller I have:

```
@items = Item.order("group_name")
```

Then in my view I can iterate through it:

```
- @items.each do |item|
  %p= item.name
```

What would be the cleanest and most efficient approach to produce something like this:

```html
<strong>Group Name 1</strong>
<p>Item 1</p>
<p>Item 2</p>
<strong>Group Name 2</strong>
<p>Item 1</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
@items = Item.sanitized_and_ordered
```

Model

```
class Item <<  ActiveRecord::Base
scope :ordered_group ,order('group_name')

class << self
   def sanitized_and_ordered
      ordered_group.group_by {|item| item.group_name}
   end
 end
end
```

View

```
- @items.each_pair do |key,value|
  %p= key
   - value.each do |item|
      %p= item.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the group_by method does what you're looking for. There's a pretty nice overview here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month